# Is there a way to empty my hands?

Tags: alien-isolation

I just crafted my first medkit! I'm so proud! I opened my radial menu to check that it was there like it's supposed to be and it was. I'm the proud owner of a single flare, and a single medkit. Yay me right?

Post this monumental achievement, I noticed that after opening the radial menu I had accidentally selected my flare and am now holding it in my right hand. Now its taking up space on my screen and bothering me. Is there a way to empty my hand of an item? (without using it or dropping it on the ground)

Comment: I haven't found one. Especially annoying since before you get the medkit, your only possession is a flare and it's easy to mistakenly pop it off and waste it.

Comment: I've found a workaround, but it's a workaround and not a 'real' solution. After you get the revolver, you can scroll down on your mouse and it will put the flare away and re-equip your revolver. Since the revolver isn't shown on the screen unless your actively aiming at something, this sort of works. (Not sure how you would do this on console)

Comment: @Ender on console you hold B and select revolver from a radial menu.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no way to empty your hands, you just have to select something else from the radial menu.

This seems a bit of a design oversight, but it only lasts a level or so before you pick up the revolver and that becomes the default thing in your hands.

It's annoying, but I suspect that they didn't bother with a 'deselect' mechanic because players would only need it for about a level or so, meaning that it would only add confusion.

Answer (score 13):

If you load your last save, then you'll resume with nothing in your hands. So find a save point, save, then load current save. Voila, empty hands.

Comment: I wish I had more than one upvote to give, this is a great idea.

Answer (score -1):

Tap L1 and you put away your selected item